# Programming in C# question

Tags: c#

After creating this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, and Welcome to Shell Bomber!\n");

Console.WriteLine("In this game you will calculate the distance\n");

Console.WriteLine("a shell will rise and travel along the ground ^_^\n");

Console.WriteLine("theta = ?");           // initial angle that you will ask for from the user

double theta = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("v_o = ?");          // initial velocity that you will ask for from the user

double v_o = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Calculate v_ox");       //Calculate vox = v_ocos(theta

double v_ox = v_o * Math.Cos(theta);      //Use the Math.Cos(theta) method

theta = theta * Math.PI / 180.0;    // Converts from degrees to radians

Console.ReadLine();
```

Is the program automatically going to convert the value of double v_ox = v_o * Math.Cos(theta) to a value from the user's input of an angle for theta and an initial value? Because when I run it, the program is not calculating the value? Did I do something wrong or is that just how I made it work?

Comment: What makes you think it's not calculating the value? Are you viewing it in debug mode?

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189087/does-anybody-know-how-to-write-the-code-for-this-physics-equation-in-c.

Comment: Lucky for him, you can't get -ve rep here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert `theta` into radians **before** you calculate v_ox.

Once you've done that, just write the value to the console:

```
Console.WriteLine("Calculate v_ox");       //Calculate vox = v_ocos(theta 

theta = theta * Math.PI / 180.0;    // Converts from degrees to radians 
double v_ox = v_o * Math.Cos(theta);      //Use the Math.Cos(theta) method 

Console.WriteLine("v_ox == {0}", v_ox); // Show this, if you want to see the value

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the program isn't showing you the value, it is because you never `WriteLine()` the result.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just missing the line where you output the result to the console? Maybe something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The calculated value is: {0}", theta);
```